# Unity Navmesh Performance Issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, navigation, agent-based-modeling, navmesh

I am currently working on a fire evacuation project using Unity Engine navmesh component. However, when I increase the number of agents, the performance of evacuation decreases significantly. Some agents are waiting very long time to evacuate. Do you know how can I solve this navmesh agent performance issue ?

[image: Evacuation Script]

Comment: Provide gifs and pictures. Show us your code if you think that has to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your `SetDestination` to `Start()`.

```
public Transform hedef;
NavMeshAgent agent;

void Start()
{
    agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    agent.SetDestination(hedef.position);
}
```

Based on the [`NavMesh`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMeshAgent.SetDestination.html) docs, you are updating and recreating the agent's path **every** frame. I do not see a reason to do this unless your `hedef` position changes, which from what I can tell from your use case, it should not. If it does happen to change, then gradually ping units that the position has changed, so you do not have any stuttering when Unity recalculates their pathing.

Comment: Thank you I have tried it but still some agents are waiting to move.

Comment: @EnesDoğukanÖzgener How many agents do you have active ?

Comment: And are you getting any errors? Are any agents getting knocked off the navmesh? And how long are they waiting to move? Milliseconds, seconds, minutes? Are they just getting stuck on something?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I solved the problem I changed the computer power and graphic card settings

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to provide more detail because if your agent going out of the door or something like this you can use a list or queue to just active first